# What causes Tensorflow Import Error: DLL load failed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using Anaconda environment on Windows 10. I have installed tensorflow-gpu using pip and when I try to import tensorflow, I get this import error below. I have tried to use cpu version of tensorflow and to reinstall all packages with new conda environment. My python is version 3.7 and tensorflow-gpu version 2.1.0.

```
    >>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Määritettyä osaa ei löydy.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ossik\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Määritettyä osaa ei löydy.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Do you have any idea what causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to downgrade and install tensorflow.

`pip install tensorflow==2.0`

- if you use gpu

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.0`

- or try downloading these visual studio files
  [click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have a CPU(probably old), which can not support AVX instructions (for example, Intel Pentium or similar). You could solve this problem using this approach:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

Go here: [link with tensorflow 2.1.0 wheels which has been precompiled with SSE2 instructions](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.1.0/py37/CPU%2BGPU/cuda102cudnn76sse2).

Download `wheel` to your project, then install tensorflow using `pip install <filename.wheel>`.
And try again - error should be solved

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have pretty new CPU (i7-6820hq) which should have AVX support. However, the simple answer by Sai YuvaTeja solved the problem.