# TENSORFLOW ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, importerror

I tried to import tensorflow on anaconda but received the following error message.  I am not sure what I need to do to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: What's the version of Tensorflow ?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308343/what-causes-tensorflow-import-error-dll-load-failed

Comment: @abdou_dev it's 2.6.0

Comment: followed the steps in the link but it doesn't work.  i receive error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: What answer you've followed?

Comment: You should uninstall Tensorflow before

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your version :

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

If you use python 3 , replace pip with pip3 :

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0
```

Comment: I received this error message when trying to install tensorflow 2.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0

Comment: Could you please check the version of Python ( x64 or x86 ) ?